# Confusing headlight issue

Tags: dodge, headlight, caravan

I have a 2001 dodge caravan. Issue is when the van is turned on it has daytime running lights. Passenger side works driver side headlight does not. When you turn the lights on it switches. Driver side works passenger does not. Then turn on high beams and it switches again. Passenger side on driver side out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!